# Spring Cloud Config Server cannot connect to git over ssh in Docker

Tags: docker, spring-cloud, dockerfile

I have setup Spring Cloud Config Server to connect to our local Stash (Atlassian Git) repository.  Running the app on its own has no problem.

When I wrap this project in a Docker image and execute it, it never loads the config from the stash repository. Here is the exception:

```
2015-09-02 16:24:18.266 ERROR 1 --- [nio-8888-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot clone or checkout repository] with root cause

com.jcraft.jsch.JSchException: UnknownHostKey: [MASKED HOST NAME]. RSA key fingerprint is 5c:73:1f:6c:09:b8:60:7b:6b:38:c9:c0:42:68:27:05
at com.jcraft.jsch.Session.checkHost(Session.java:786)
at com.jcraft.jsch.Session.connect(Session.java:342)
at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.JschConfigSessionFactory.getSession(JschConfigSessionFactory.java:116)
at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.SshTransport.getSession(SshTransport.java:136)
at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.TransportGitSsh$SshFetchConnection.<init>(TransportGitSsh.java:262)
at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.TransportGitSsh.openFetch(TransportGitSsh.java:161)
at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.FetchProcess.executeImp(FetchProcess.java:136)
at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.FetchProcess.execute(FetchProcess.java:122)
at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.Transport.fetch(Transport.java:1115)
at org.eclipse.jgit.api.FetchCommand.call(FetchCommand.java:130)
at org.eclipse.jgit.api.CloneCommand.fetch(CloneCommand.java:178)
at org.eclipse.jgit.api.CloneCommand.call(CloneCommand.java:125)
at org.springframework.cloud.config.server.JGitEnvironmentRepository.cloneToBasedir(JGitEnvironmentRepository.java:251)
at org.springframework.cloud.config.server.JGitEnvironmentRepository.copyRepository(JGitEnvironmentRepository.java:224)
at org.springframework.cloud.config.server.JGitEnvironmentRepository.createGitClient(JGitEnvironmentRepository.java:212)
at org.springframework.cloud.config.server.JGitEnvironmentRepository.findOne(JGitEnvironmentRepository.java:102)
at org.springframework.cloud.config.server.MultipleJGitEnvironmentRepository.findOne(MultipleJGitEnvironmentRepository.java:84)
at org.springframework.cloud.config.server.EnvironmentController.labelled(EnvironmentController.java:108)
at org.springframework.cloud.config.server.EnvironmentController.defaultLabel(EnvironmentController.java:95)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:221)
at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:137)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:110)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:776)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:705)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:959)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:893)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:966)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:857)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:622)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:842)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:291)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.EndpointWebMvcAutoConfiguration$ApplicationContextHeaderFilter.doFilterInternal(EndpointWebMvcAutoConfiguration.java:295)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at org.springframework.boot.actuate.trace.WebRequestTraceFilter.doFilterInternal(WebRequestTraceFilter.java:102)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:77)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:85)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.MetricsFilter.doFilterInternal(MetricsFilter.java:68)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:219)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:142)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:518)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1091)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:668)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1521)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1478)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Here is the contents of my Dockerfile:

```
FROM java:8
VOLUME /tmp
ADD config-manager-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar config-manager.jar
RUN bash -c 'touch /config-manager.jar'
RUN mkdir -p /root/.ssh
RUN chmod 700 /root/.ssh
ADD id_rsa_acp /root/.ssh/id_rsa
RUN chmod 600 /root/.ssh/id_rsa
RUN echo -e "Host [MASKED DOMAIN]\n\tStrictHostKeyChecking no\n" >> /root/.ssh/config
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-Dspring.profiles.active=docker","-Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom","-jar","/config-manager.jar"]
```

Note that the id_rsa_acp file sits alongside the Dockerfile in the same directory.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem come from the ssh config file replace the RUN command with this one

```
RUN bash -c 'echo -e "Host [MASKED DOMAIN]\n\tStrictHostKeyChecking no\n" >> /root/.ssh/config >> /root/.ssh/config'
```

Comment: Just curious why two redirects?